# Parsing dynamic CSV through Node and writing schema in Mongo

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');

var csv = require("fast-csv");

var fs = require('fs');

const Contact = require('../models/contacts');

var DIR = './uploads/';

var upload = multer({ dest: DIR }).single('file');

//uploading a csv
router.post('/uploads', function (req, res, next) {
    var path = '';
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // An error occurred when uploading
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(422).send("an Error occured")
        }
        // No error occured.
        path = req.file.path;
        return res.send("Upload Completed for " + path);
    });
})
```

I want to import a dynamic CSV file using MEAN Stack. Uploaded the file using Angular, and it was uploaded in uploads folder, I don't want to hard quote the data type because, i want to upload random CSV and use them for further purposes. All the examples I see were based on a pre-defined CSV (EX: First Name, Rank Number etc) which shouldn't be in my case. Kindly help

This is my Route.js, the file got uploaded in Uploads folder, Now how to parse further, How the schema is written dynamically in mongo

Comment: try using papa-parse, amazing set of tools to do with csv to json and json to csv conversion.

Comment: Will this work for a random dynamic CSV or only for the CSV with known headers?

Comment: It works for random csv files as well.